# SFDX: Auto-Generated Log Levels are set to 'INFO' by default

Tags: salesforcedx, logging

I have an understanding of how debug logs work with the Developer Console and how to configure the log levels below in the UI, however, I'm unsure of how to set these log levels in VS Code with SFDX with the new replay debugger. Below is the top line of the log:

```
43.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

Where do I need to configure the log levels in DX? I've looked through the SFDX Developer Guide, specifically on [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_log_messages.htm) and was unable to find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this is to run the `SFDX: Turn on Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger` command. By doing so, your debug level will start to show the correct configuration.